# a-frame をandroidのwebviewで表示したい

Tags: android, java, webview

WebGLを利用したWebVRフレームワーク「a-frame」を利用したwebページ、
androidのchromeアプリではなく、webviewを利用してアプリ上に表示しようと考えています。

試しに、a-frameの公式サイトを表示しようと、下記のような形で実装をしてみたのですが、画面が真っ白なままで、何も表示されません。

```
private WebView m_WebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    m_WebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.vr_webView);

    m_WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    m_WebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    m_WebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    m_WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    m_WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    m_WebView.loadUrl("https://aframe.io");
}
```

検証に使った端末は
・Xperia X Performance (Android 7.0)
・Galaxy S6 Edge (Android 6.0.1)
です。

どなたか解決策をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？
※アプリを実行時に下記のログが表示されていました。

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "No DPDB device match.", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Failed to recalculate device parameters.", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Using fallback Android device measurements.", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(139)] "Failed to load viewer profile: %s", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (139)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distortionCoefficients' of undefined", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "THREE.WebGLRenderer", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (107)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "No DPDB device match.", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Failed to recalculate device parameters.", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Using fallback Android device measurements.", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(139)] "Failed to load viewer profile: %s", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (139)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distortionCoefficients' of undefined", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Error loading online DPDB!", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(137)] "Error loading online DPDB!", source: https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js (137)
```

Answer (score 1):

WebViewの代わりにCrosswalkを使用すると簡単に動かせました。
Crosswalkの導入はこちらを参考に
http://qiita.com/niusounds/items/ecd51016cda91c5c3a5e

Answer (score 1):

AndroidManifest.xml に下記のパーミッションのエントリーはありますか？

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

下記のコードで特に問題なく表示されました（Xperia Ace; Android 9）：

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webView = new WebView(this);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl("https://aframe.io");

        setContentView(webView);
    }
}
```

[image: スクリーンショット]